# Generating sets of integers in C#

Tags: c#, set

In F#, you can generate a set of numbers, just by saying [1..100].

I want to do something similar in C#.  This is what I have come up with so far:

```
public static int[] To(this int start, int end)
{
    var result = new List<int>();
    for(int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        result.Add(i);
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

By doing this, I can now create a set by saying 1.To(100)

Unfortunately, this is not nearly as readable as [1..100].  Has anyone come up with a better way to do this in C#?  Is it more readable if it is lowercase?  1.to(100), for instance?  Or, is "To" a bad word?  Is something like 1.Through(100) more readable?

Just looking for some thoughts.  Has anyone else come up with a more elegant solution?

**EDIT:**
After reading the responses, I have re-written my To method using the range:

```
public static int[] To(this int start, int end)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(start, end - start + 1).ToArray();
}
```

I am still looking for thoughts on the readability of 1.To(100)

Comment: Do you have a specific need to create an array and not IEnumerable<int>? If so I'm curious what your reasons are for that requirement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enumerable.Range(1, 100);

Comment: That method is useful.  Thanks.  It is less readable than 1.To(100), but I can use it in the implementation, of To() at least.

Comment: I should expand on why I think it is less readable... it is because I actually need an array, which becomes: Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray()

Comment: I would say that 1.To(100) can be misunderstood. To me it sounds like a cast. Also Enumerable.Range has the advantage of being implemented in the .net framework and therefore is probably familiar to more people.

Comment: And that is what I am looking for.  I really don't want to write Enumerable.Range(5, 2).ToArray() to mean new[]{5,6,7}.  I understand that 5.To(7) might be confusing, but it reads better than the Enumerable line.  I am looking for suggestions that are more readable than 5.To(7)

Comment: Adding extension methods to something like int makes me feel a bit icky.

Answer (score 5):

I like the idea of using `To`. The alternative `Enumerable.Range` has a subtle flaw imo. The second parameter is **not** the *value* of the last element, it is the *length* of the enumeration. This is what I've done in the past:

```
public IEnumerable<int> To(this int start, int stop)
{
  while (start <= stop)
    yield return start++;
}
```

EDIT: If you want the result as an `int[]`, just add `.ToArray()`:

```
int[] theSet = 1.To(100).ToArray();
```

Comment: Yes, good point on the length, not value subtlety.  I need it to be an array, not an IEnumerable, so yield doesn't gain me any benefit here.  See my edits in the OP

Comment: You can do that, but you have really sacrificed readability when the set is generated...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I reread the OP and realised that I had written exactly what you wrote... Sorry about that. :-)

Comment: This is a clever use of extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like `Set(1,100)` or `IntSequence(1,100)` is easier to read than using an extension method.

Personal opinion though...

Comment: I'd avoid "Set" because of it's meaning wrt:properties, and I'd prefer to see Sequence<int> than IntSequence

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to your own question is fine.  Just don't use a List if you are concerned about performance.  Constructing a list and constantly expanding it is foolish.  Just construct an array of the appropriate size. Use an extension method

```
public static int[] To(this int num)
    {
        //do work
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're worried too much that the language doesn't exactly express the particular syntactic thing that you want.

The way I see it, extension methods are a nice bit of sugar, but I wonder if you're really using it so much to justify the "surprise" of the extension method.

Within the domain of the language C#, it is more appropriate to spell out via the method name what you're trying to do.  This feels more like Ruby than C#.  This feels more like it wants to be in class by itself, especially if you wanted to add ranges with skip patterns (ie, the numbers from 1 to 10 by threes).  I think that

```
public class RangedArray {
    public static int[] Generate(int from, into to, int by=1) { /* ... */ }
}
```

is a perfectly acceptable to express this in C#.

Comment: I agree.  However, your default param is C# 4...  confusing for some right now (pre rtm)