# How can I translate this Groovy function to C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, groovy

I would like to translate to C# the following Groovy code

```
def find_perfect_numbers(def number) {
  (2..number).findAll { x-> (1..(x/2)).findAll{ x % it == 0 }.sum() == x }
}
```

which I got from [here](http://vasya10.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/groovy-olc-3-perfect-numbers/).

This is what I have, but it's not ready yet, doesn't compile either. I don't understand the groovy code good enough.

```
public List<int> find_perfect_numbers(int number)
{
    List<int> lst = new List<int>();

    lst = 2.To(number).FindAll(x => (1.To(x/2)).FindAll( x % it == 0).Sum() == x);

    return lst;
}
```

I can't translate the part `x % it == 0` (because "it" is an index).

- I want the C# code to look as much like the groovy function as possible. Specifically, the line `lst = 2.To( ....`.
- I don't want to use a different solution to find perfect numbers (I have another working function already). For me this is only about the syntax, not about a good "perfect numbers function".
- It's OK to create new (extension) functions that help doing this, just like the To function I used:

For the To function above I have used this StackOverflow function:
[Generating sets of integers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371237/generating-sets-of-integers-in-c-sharp)
and changed it a little so that it returns a List of int instead of an array of int

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<int> To(this int start, int end)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(start, end - start + 1).ToList();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

**=== Update ===**

This is what I have now, but it's not working yet, I get 
*DivideByZeroException was unhandled* at the part `s.value % s.idx == 0`:

```
lst = 2.To(number).FindAll(x => ((1.To(x / 2)).Select((y, index) => new {value = y, idx = index}).Where( s => s.value % s.idx == 0).Sum(t => t.value) == (decimal)x));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it myself.

```
lst = 2.To(number)
       .FindAll(x => ((1.To(x / 2))
       .Select((y, index) => new {value = y, idx = index+1})
       .Where( s => x % s.idx == 0)
       .Sum(t => t.value) == (decimal)x));
```

Not as pretty as the Groovy one, but it works.